# Is there a simple macro variable in Hive?

Tags: hive, macros

I'm used to creating macro variables in SAS. Is there an equivalent option in Hive?

Answer (score 1):

Since Hive 0.12.0, it introduced macros to HiveQL, prior to which they could only be created in Java. Source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/DropMacro
You can also define some variable using hive var.Source:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/60309/working-with-variables-in-hive-hive-shell-and-beel.html
Hope this help.